# Load XML data into SQL Server, special XML structure

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, bulkinsert

I'm trying to load XML data into a SQL Server table.

The XML file is:

```
<root>
   <Company ID="183">
      <User UserName="Kim" />
      <User UserName = "Joe" />
   </Company>
 <Company ID="123">
      <User UserName="George" />
      <User UserName = "Sal" />
   </Company>
</root>
```

I would like to get a table of UserName that has both the company ID and the UserName.
for this example:

```
ID      UserName
---     --------
183     Kim
183     Joe
123     George
123     Sal
```

I've tried a few things, such as looping through all usernames of each Company, but this is quite complex especially when I have more than 2 layers to suit for this solution.

Another thing I tried is:

```
SELECT
t.c.query('./UserName').value('.','varchar(20)') AS A ,
(
    SELECT
    t1.c1.value('@ID', 'varchar(10)')
    FROM @x.nodes('/root/Company')AS t1(c1)
)
FROM @x.nodes('/root/Company/User')AS t(c)
```

but I get an error that the subquery has more than 1 value.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your say *SQL* but you really mean **SQL Server** - try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<root>
   <Company ID="183">
      <User UserName="Kim" />
      <User UserName = "Joe" />
   </Company>
 <Company ID="123">
      <User UserName="George" />
      <User UserName = "Sal" />
   </Company>
</root>'

SELECT
    CompanyID = Comp.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int'),
    UserName = USerTbl.value('(@UserName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('/root/Company') T(Comp)
CROSS APPLY
    Comp.nodes('User') AS T2(UserTbl)
```

That gives me the output you're looking for.